# powerbi _ broght two different queries ,and don't show as I expected in the table

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I broght data using two different sql from odbc db at the power bi.
1 query _ date / sales number / location
2 query _ date / another sales number /location

I brought sales number and another sales number from query 1, 2 to the same table as below pic.
and query 1 sales number shows right per each location.
but query 2 another sales number just show total number per each location.

Why does this happening and solve the problem?

[image]